# method find of object range failed in vba

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I have written a code that finds all the dye word and sum all the dye word value.

Here is the code

```
Dim name As String
name = "dye"

Dim findDyeRange As Range
Set findDyeRange = Range("Q10:S61")

Set firstDyeWord = findDyeRange.Find(name)

If firstDyeWord Is Nothing Then
    msgbox "nothing found"
Else
    firstDyeValue = firstDyeWord.Offset(0, 1).Value
    Set secondDyeWord = findDyeRange.FindNext(firstDyeWord)
    
    If secondDyeWord.Address = firstDyeWord.Address Then
        MsgBox firstDyeValue
        Exit Sub
    Else
        secondDyeValue = secondDyeWord.Offset(0, 1).Value
        Set thirdDyeWord = findDyeRange.FindNext(secondDyeWord)
        
        If thirdDyeWord.Address = firstDyeWord.Address Then
            MsgBox firstDyeValue + secondDyeValue
            Exit Sub
        Else
            thirdDyeValue = thirdDyeWord.Offset(0, 1).Value
            Set fourthDyeWord = findDyeRange.FindNext(thirdDyeWord)
            
            If fourthDyeWord.Address = firstDyeWord.Address Then
                MsgBox firstDyeValue + secondDyeValue + thirdDyeValue
                Exit Sub
            Else
                fourthDyeValue = fourthDyeWord.Offset(0, 1).Value
                Set fifthDyeWord = findDyeRange.FindNext(fourthDyeWord)
                
                If fifthDyeWord.Address = firstDyeWord.Address Then
                    MsgBox firstDyeValue + secondDyeValue + thirdDyeValue + fourthDyeValue
                    Exit Sub
                Else
                    fifthDyeValue = fifthDyeWord.Offset(0, 1).Value
                    Set sixthDyeWord = findDyeRange.FindNext(fifthDyeWord)
                    
                    If sixthDyeWord.Address = firstDyeWord.Address Then
                        MsgBox firstDyeValue + secondDyeValue + thirdDyeValue + fourthDyeValue + fifthDyeValue
                        Exit Sub
                    Else
                        sixthDyeValue = sixthDyeWord.Offset(0, 1).Value
                        MsgBox firstDyeValue + secondDyeValue + thirdDyeValue + fourthDyeValue + fifthDyeValue + sixthDyeValue
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
End If
```

the code runs well. But when I removes the msgbox and set a code then it throws an error.

I want this code

```
If firstDyeWord Is Nothing Then
        Range("A9").value = 7
```

But it throws error "method find of object range failed in vba"

Help Please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation of the [Range.Find method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) you must at least specify the parameters `LookIn`, `LookAt`, `SearchOrder` and `MatchByte` when using `Find()` otherwise it uses what ever was used last by either VBA or the user interface.
Since you cannot know what your users used last in the user interface your search might randomly work and randomly come up with wrong results. Therefore always specify all of these 4 parameters to make it reliable.

Additionally you must specify in which workbook/worksheet your ranges are. Otherwise Excel guesses and it might guess the wrong sheet.

Make sure to declare **all** your variables properly. I recommend always to activate `Option Explicit`: In the VBA editor go to *Tools* › *Options* › *[Require Variable Declaration](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html)*.

```vb
Public Sub Example()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'set your workbook and worksheet!
    
    Dim name As String
    name = "dye"
    
    Dim findDyeRange As Range
    Set findDyeRange = ws.Range("Q10:S61") 'specify in which sheet the range is
    
    Dim firstDyeWord As Range
    Set firstDyeWord = findDyeRange.Find(What:=name, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchByte=False)
    
    If firstDyeWord Is Nothing Then
        'dye was NOT found
        ws.Range("A9").Value = 7 'specify in which sheet the range is
    Else
        'do something else if dye was found
    End If
End Sub
```

// Edit (see comment)

If this is used in an event like `Worksheet_Change` you need to turn off events before writing to a cell. Otherwise this will trigger another event which will trigger another event … and you get stuck in an endless loop of events, which cannot work:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'set your workbook and worksheet!
    
    Dim name As String
    name = "dye"
    
    Dim findDyeRange As Range
    Set findDyeRange = ws.Range("Q10:S61") 'specify in which sheet the range is
    
    Dim firstDyeWord As Range
    Set firstDyeWord = findDyeRange.Find(What:=name, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchByte=False)
    
    If firstDyeWord Is Nothing Then
        'dye was NOT found
        On Error Goto REACTIVATE_EVENTS 'in any case of error reactivate events
        Application.EnableEvents = False 'disable events or .Value = 7 triggers another change event.
        ws.Range("A9").Value = 7 'specify in which sheet the range is
        Application.EnableEvents = True 'make sure you never leave events disabled otherwise they will stay off until you restart Excel.
    Else
        'do something else if dye was found
    End If

    Exit Sub
REACTIVATE_EVENTS:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then Err.Raise Err.Number, Err.Source, Err.Description, Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext 'show error message if there was an error.
End Sub
```

Comment: nothing helped bro. Suddenly I discovered that if I create a button from developer tools and assign this code as macro then this code runs perfectly. But when I assign this in worksheet_Change then it throws that error. Hope this will help you to find the solution.

Comment: @Mehedi well you didn't tell that you were using an event. When using events the code needs to be different of course. Check out my edit.

Comment: This is well but here is a problem that it disabled my undo method. I can't undo anything on the worksheet. Pls look at it.

Comment: Macros cannot be reverted using the undo method. That is not possible. After your macro changes cell values (which this code `ws.Range("A9").Value = 7` does) undo does not work and is not available. There is no workaround.

Comment: you didn't getting me. I also know that macros cannot be reverted. I am saying that any other changes in my worksheet is not reverting. Hope understand.

Comment: Yes because `Worksheet_Change` runs on **every** cell change you make in the worksheet and because your macro changes cell values `ws.Range("A9").Value = 7 ` this blocks undo. This is a normal behaviour. The only way to prevent this is not changing values. Everytime an event macro changes a cell value undo is blocked and reset.